# Send POST requests to Solr 7.2.1 from Sitecore 9.1

Tags: solr

For some search requests to SOLR 7.2.1 I have to use quite long queries (oversees 8192 symbols), as a result I'm getting (414) URI Too Long error.

I've already investigated many articles and tried solutions from them, but any doesn't help:

1. https://wcms.clearpeople.com/insights/blog/2017/june/using-post-to-communicate-with-solr-from-sitecore
2. https://vicent.dev/post/2017/04/28/Using-POST-to-communicate-with-Solr-from-Sitecore
3. [ContentSearch Solr SendPostRequests settings throw exception](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/contentsearch-solr-sendpostrequests-settings-throw-exception)

Is there any working solution for Sitecore 9.1 and Solr 7.2.1?

Comment: You seen [this](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/191459) already?

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but it does not suit our needs.

Comment: but we can send a POST request to SOLR without sitecore , is there any dependecny on using Sitecore for the POST request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally got an answer from Sitecore Support - unfortunately there is no way to send POST requests to Solr (7.2.1) from Sitecore (at least 9+). Hope it will be fixed soon, but as of now - there is an official response:

Thank you for contacting our support team. From the provided description, it looks like you've faced a bug with reference number 288837, because of which setting "ContentSearch.Solr.SendPostRequests" does not work with value "true". More information about public reference numbers can be found here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

According to our tickets history, changing the "ContentSearch.Solr.SendPostRequests" value to "false" and increasing a header size as per the mentioned by you [KB article](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/191459) is the only known workaround at the moment.